# how can i create loop using xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, pycharm, webdriver

```
#start
i=0
r=("('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[")
p=("]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/a')")

for f in range(7):
   i = i+1
   browser.find_element_by_xpath("{}{}{}".format(r,i,p)).click()
#end
```

error i am getting =selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/a') because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this :

```
r=("('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[")
p=("]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/a')")
```

do this :

```
i = 0
for f in range(7):
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{0}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/a".format(str(i))).click()
 i = i+1
```

I would still suggest to not use this absolute xpath instead use relative xpath